# GridLayout showing only first column

Tags: android

I am trying for over 2 hours to figure out why my GridLayout shows only the first column.
I experimented with various options like `layout_weight` and `layout_columnWeight`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp">

    <GridLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:text="Type:"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerEvpRecordType"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:entries="@array/evp_record_types"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
</GridLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are explicitly putting your `Spinner` inside of the second column while the `TextView` is spanning over the first two so they overlap. Try removing the `android:layout_column` property in both `TextView` and `Spinner`. But you will still have to work with the columns' weights in order to achieve the desired proportion.